# Elementor Elements are not loading after installing the Yoast plugin

Tags: wordpress, elementor, yoast

While editing a page, the Elements are not loading in to the editor. The Elements look like InActive and the one loader is rounding on top of that.

To identify the conflict, I have InActivated the installed plugins one by one and found Yoast SEO is causing the issue. Once I Inactivated the Yoast, the elements started loading.

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the memory issue. The assigned memory in PHP(in cPanel) was 128MB. I have increased it in to 512 MB. Then the issue solved.
Go to website.com/cpanel -> Select PHP Version -> Advanced > Memory_limit > Increase to 512.

And refresh the elementor page.